# Alterar información en el inspector de código y luego hacer submit (insert)

Tags: php, jquery

Mi caso es el siguiente:

Tengo una tabla que como verán tiene un botón "crear factura" con un atributo nro_pedido="".

```
<table class="tabla tabla-pedido table table-bordered table-responsive-sm">
        
        <thead class="thead-dark">    
          <tr class="text-center">
            <th class="align-middle letra-tabla">N°</th>
            <th class="align-middle letra-tabla">Cliente</th>
            <th class="align-middle letra-tabla">Fecha</th>
            <th class="align-middle letra-tabla">Estado</th>
            <th class="align-middle letra-tabla">N° Factura</th>
            <th class="align-middle letra-tabla">Estado del Pago</th>
            <th class="align-middle letra-tabla">Importe Final</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody id="myTable" class="cuerpo-tabla-pedido"> 
          <?php foreach ($pedidos as $key => $value): ?>

            <tr>

              <td class="letra-tabla align-middle p-1 p-md-2">
                <div class="rounded-pill text-center">
                    <?php echo $value["ID"]; ?>
                </div>
              </td>

              <td class="align-middle text-center letra-tabla p-1 p-md-2">
                <a href="">
                    <?php echo $value["Nombre_Cliente"]; ?> <?php echo $value["Apellido_Cliente"]; ?>
                </a>
              </td>

              <td class="align-middle letra-tabla p-1 p-md-2 text-center">
                <?php echo $value["Fecha_Pedido"]; ?>
              </td>

              <td class="align-middle letra-tabla p-1 p-md-2 text-center">
                <?php echo $value["Estado_Pedido"]; ?>
              </td>

              <td class="align-middle letra-tabla p-1 p-md-2 text-center">
                <?php if($value["Nro_Factura"] != null){
                    echo $value["Nro_Factura"];
                }else{ ?>
                    <div>
                    <!-- Facturar -->
                         <button type="button" class="crear-factura btn btn-warning" name="facturar" value="ok" nro_pedido="<?=$value["ID"]; ?>">Crear Factura</button>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
              </td>

              <td class="align-middle letra-tabla p-1 p-md-2 text-center">
                <?php if($value["Estado_Pago"] != null){
                    echo $value["Estado_Pago"];
                }else{ ?>
                    <div>
                        <span>-</span>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
              </td>

              <td class="text-center align-middle cantidad-tabla p-1 p-md-2 text-center">
                <?php if($value["Estado_Pago"] != null){ ?>
                    <span class="cantidad-tabla">$ </span><?php echo $value["Importe_Final"]; ?>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                    <div>
                        <span>-</span>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
              </td>
              
              <td class="align-middle p-1 p-md-2">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <form>
                   <input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="modificar-gasto">
                   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$value["id"]; ?>">
                   <input type="hidden" name="estado" value="<?=$value["Estado"]; ?>">
                   <input type="hidden" name="categoria" value="<?=$value["Id_Categoria"]; ?>">
                   <input type="hidden" name="subcategoria" value="<?=$value["Id_Subcategoria"]; ?>">
                   <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?=$value["Descripcion"]; ?>">
                   <input type="hidden" name="monto" value="<?=$value["Importe"]; ?>">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary boton-tabla"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </td>

            </tr>
        
          <?php endforeach ?>
        </tbody>

      </table>
```

Este es el jquery con el que capto el id de pedido y consulto la base de datos:

```
/*---- Acceder al Boton Facturar en consultar-pedidos ---*/
$(".tabla .cuerpo-tabla-pedido tr td .crear-factura").click(function(){

    /*Pone en cero los productos para que no se acumulen en el Modal*/
    $('#modal-factura .modal-body .productos').html(null);
    /*Pone en cero el el input descuento*/
    $('#modal-factura .modal-body .contenedor-suma-factura .descuento input').val("");
    
    var idPedido = $(this).attr("nro_pedido");

    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("consultarPedido", idPedido);

    $.ajax({

        url: "ajax/ventas.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(respuesta){

            /*Captura id de pedido*/
            var idPedido = respuesta[0]["ID_Pedido"];
            

            $('#modal-factura .modal-header h5 span').html(idPedido);

            var cantidadProductos = respuesta.length; 
            var arraySubtotales = [];

            /*Crea la row de un producto*/
            for (var i = 0; i < cantidadProductos; i++) {
            
                /*Captura producto*/
                var contador = i + 1;
                var codigoProducto = respuesta[i]["Codigo_Producto"];
                var cantidadProducto = respuesta[i]["Cantidad"];
                var precioProducto = respuesta[i]["PU"];
                    
                $('#modal-factura .modal-body .productos').append(

                    '<div class="row mb-2">'+

                        '<div class="text-center col-1 col-sm-1">'+
                            +contador+
                        '</div>'+

                        '<div class="text-center col-4 col-sm-4">'+
                          ''+codigoProducto+''+
                        '</div>'+

                        '<div class="text-center col-3 col-sm-3">'+
                          +cantidadProducto+
                        '</div>'+

                        '<div class="precio-producto-factura subtotales text-center col-4 col-sm-4" precio="'+precioProducto+'">'+
                          '<p class="m-0">$<span>'+precioProducto+'</span></p>'+
                        '</div>'+

                    '</div>');

                arraySubtotales.push(Number(precioProducto));
            }
```

Este botón me abre una ventana modal con los datos de la factura (con la consulta ajax que se ve arriba). Aquí está la ventana modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-factura" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">

        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">

          <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">

              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">
                Factura N°<span>999</span>
              </h5>

              <!-- contenedor check, aparece cuando se da click en facturar -->
              <div class="contenedor-check d-none my-auto ml-2 text-success">
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
              </div>

              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Fecha -->
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-12">
                    

                    <div class="contenedor-fecha d-flex justify-content-end mb-3">

                     <input type="date" class="fecha" value="<?php echo date("Y-n-j"); ?>">

                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Tablita -->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">

                    <!-- Encabezado Tabla -->
                    <div class="row mb-2 bg-info text-white rounded p-1">

                      <div class="font-weight-bold text-center col-1 col-sm-1">
                        N°
                      </div>

                      <div class="font-weight-bold text-center col-4 col-sm-4">
                        Código
                      </div>

                      <div class="font-weight-bold text-center col-3 col-sm-3">
                        Cant.
                      </div>

                      <div class="font-weight-bold text-center col-4 col-sm-4">
                        Precio
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- Cuerpo de la tabla -->
                    <div class="row">

                      <div class="productos col-12">
                        
                        <!-- Aquí van los productos -->

                      </div>

                    </div>

                     <!-- Fila que contiene los totales -->
                    <div class="row mb-3">

                      <div class="offset-4 col-8">

                        <!-- Contenedor totales, recuadro -->
                        <div class="contenedor-suma-factura border border-primary py-3 pr-3">
                          
                          <!-- Sub Total -->
                          <div class="subtotal row">

                            <div class="font-weight-bold text-right col-7 col-sm-7">
                              Subtotal:
                            </div>

                            <div class="subtotal-valor d-flex text-center col-5 col-sm-5">

                              <!-- Boton para Descuento -->
                              <button type="button" class="botonDescuento btn btn-light btn-sm">
                                <i class="botonAbajoDescuento fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                                <i class="botonArribaDescuento fas fa-chevron-up d-none"></i>
                              </button>

                              <p class="m-0 ml-1">$ <span>99999.99</span></p>

                            </div>

                          </div>

                          <!-- Descuento -->
                          <div class="descuento row mt-3 d-none">
                            <div class="font-weight-bold text-right col-7 col-sm-7">
                              Descuento (%):
                            </div>
                            <div class="valor-descuento text-center col-5 col-sm-5">
                              <input type="number" class="float-right text-right" style="width: 100%;">
                            </div>

                          </div>

                          <!-- Total -->
                          <div class="total row mt-3">
                            <div class="font-weight-bold text-right col-7 col-sm-7">
                              Importe Total:
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center col-5 col-sm-5">
                              <p class="m-0">$ <span>99999.99</span></p>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>

                      </div>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Observaciones -->
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-12">
                    

                    <div class="contenedor-observaciones my-3">

                     <input type="text" class="observaciones form-control" placeholder="Observaciones">

                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <!-- Contenedor de la botonera inferior del modal -->
              <div class="contenedor-botones-modal-factura m-auto">

                <!-- boton facturar -->
                <button type="button" class="boton-modal-facturar btn btn-info">Facturar</button>

                <!-- El siguiente boton solo se activa cuando doy click en el boton facturar -->
                <button type="button" class="boton-modal-crear-pago btn btn-info d-none" ultimoIdFactura="">Crear Pago</button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Si yo previo a dar click en el botón "crear factura" en la tabla, abro el inspector de código y cambio los datos en el html (el atributo nro_factura=""). Cuando haga click, voy a estar llevando al modal informacion alterada y por lo tanto voy a darle la posibilidad al usuario de hacer un insert erroneo.
Cuál es la forma correcta de hacer un insert en la base de datos, que evite que se pueda alterar la información en el inspector de código? Si tuviera en el formulario solamente inputs que hay que rellenar no sería un problema, pero en este caso, parte de la información que utilizo para hacer el insert viene de la tabla.

Comment: No entiendo el problema que  planteas aquí. Si se pueden alterar los valores de la tabla desde el inspector de código, también desde los `input` podrían alterarse. El concepto mismo de *alterar* ¿a qué se refiere? Cuando ofreces un `input` el usuario podria escribir lo que quiera... e incluso un hacker podría usar un `input` o lo que sea para atacar tu sistema. Explícanos entonces cuál es el problema concretamente, qué es lo que debe hacer tu programa, qué dificultades tienes en concreto y qué tipo de seguridad implementas del lado del servidor, que es donde se juega la integridad del sistema.

Comment: La ventana modal trae informacion de la tabla, si antes de abrir la ventana modal cambio el atributo del botón, la informacion del modal va a cambiar. Esto era lo que no me gustaba.

Comment: Con la informacion del modal luego hago un insert. Podria estar insertando informacion erronea en la base de datos

Comment: En cuanto a la seguridad, utilizo siempre la sentencia prepare con bindparam. Y la base de datos tiene sus restricciones. Lo cierto es que en este caso las restricciones evitarian hacer un insert en la base de datos, si los datos se alteran como yo decia.

Comment: En cuestiones de seguridad estoy bastante perdido, si tenes alguna sugerencia de lectura o curso donde pueda mejorar las habilidades en cuanto a seguridad, lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando trabajas con información sensible como es tu caso, no es recomendable pasar esa información en un atributo de HTML como ya te diste cuenta es muy fácil de alterar esa información.

1.- Lo que yo te recomendaria, es que trabajes con variables de sesion `$_SESSION[]`estas no pueden ser modificadas, o si bien alguien puede alterarlas necesitaran de un conocimiento mayor.

2.- Cuando creas la informacion de tu factura ahi puedes crear esta variable de sesion ejemplo:

```
$_SESSION["nro_pedido"] = $value["ID"];
```

3.- Al momento de crear esta **variable de sesion**, tendra "vida" en todo tu proyecto, dicho de otra forma, podrás acceder a ella desde cualquier parte y realizar las validaciones correspondientes, ejemplo de como acceder a las variables de sesion:

```
echo $_SESSION['nro_pedido'];
```

4.- Te dejo un enlace para que puedas profundizar mas en el tema de manejo de sesiones en PHP:

[$_SESSION - PHP - MANUAL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: Gracias. Excelente respuesta, era lo que estaba buscando. Yo habia usado estas variables de SESSION pero no sabia que podía utilizarlas en este caso también. Lo que me generaba duda era el hecho de que sean globales, como bien vos mencionas. ¿Porque habría de utilizar una variable global si en realidad solo quiero invocarla en un fichero? Era mi duda. ¿Podría utilizar en este caso una variable $_COOKIE ?

Comment: Recuerda que las variables de $_SESSION solucionan temas de seguridad que las  $_COOKIE traen por naturaleza, recuerda que las **cookies** se almacenan del lado del cliente y las **variables de sesion** del lado del servidor ¿Cual se te hace mas segura?

Comment: Claro, entiendo. Muchas gracias! Un saludo